# SIM Rack for Virtual SMS Number hosting?

Tags: mobile, sms, telephony, kannel

I am interested in knowing the SIM Management solution or SIM Hosting platform products.  Any reliable product over Mobile SIM Hosting and access our IP.

Couple of SIM Rack product appear up on Google results, any one experience of hosting virtual mobile number and which platform was used?   Any experience of bulk SMS products using VIrtual SIM Hosting Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was tough one to find the best solution or building one from scratch, so decided to use service provider who is already offering [Virtual SMS numbers](http://www.innovativetxt.com/2-way-sms/index.html) for 25+ Countries.  They offer [SIM Hosting Service](http://www.innovativetxt.com/Virtual-SIM-Hosting/Virtual-SIM-Hosting-Services.html) as-well via API Gateway and Online Services.

There website address is http://www.innovativetxt.com/

I hope this will be helpful to people looking for Incoming or 2 way messaging solution.